# How do I split a string containing a math expression into a list?

Tags: python, string, list, split

How do I tokenize the string:

```
"2+24*48/32"
```

Into a list:

```
['2', '+', '24', '*', '48', '/', '32']
```

Comment: You want to split a string into a list, but you don't want to use .split() because it returns a list? You're contradicting yourself. If you don't want a list, then what is it you *do* want?

Comment: @Jim: I think Jibmo means that split() only allows you to specify one delimiter, so he would have to call it once for '+', once for '-', once for '/', etc...

Comment: sorry for the bad explanation, what I meant is that split will return a list, which means for the second split, I now need to iterate over strings within a list. syntaxly incorrect example..

string = "2+2-2"
list = string.split(+)
returns ['2', '+', '2-2']
now i need to iterate over 3 strings

Comment: You should mention that you're working on a program that needs to be able to evaluate these strings as arithmetic expressions. Jerub's answer covers that, but that's because he's a mindreader.

Comment: Why not just use [SymPy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/)? It should do what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It's not clear whether you are working with floats/decimals or integers ? I mean, should the '.' (or ',' for some countries) be split too ?

Answer (score 51):

It just so happens that the tokens you want split are already Python tokens, so you can use the built-in `tokenize` module.  It's almost a one-liner; this program:

```py
from io import StringIO
from tokenize import generate_tokens

STRING = 1
print(
    list(
        token[STRING]
    for token in generate_tokens(StringIO("2+24*48/32").readline)
    if token[STRING]
    )
)
```

produces this output:

```py
['2', '+', '24', '*', '48', '/', '32']
```

Comment: Great answer, I didn't realize this module existed :)

Comment: Instead or manually assigning ``STRING=1`` you could use the constant from the ``token`` module by doing a ``from token import STRING``. This is particular useful if you need several token constants.

Comment: why would such a complicated answer be rated so high? It's a pretty simple question. Whatever happened to finding the cleanest, most concise answer?

Answer (score 36):

You can use `split` from the `re` module.

[re.split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0, flags=0)](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split)

> Split string by the occurrences of pattern. If capturing parentheses
>   are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are
>   also returned as part of the resulting list.

Example code:

```
import re
data = re.split(r'(\D)', '2+24*48/32')
```

---

\D

> When the UNICODE flag is not specified, \D matches any non-digit
>   character; this is equivalent to the set [^0-9].

Answer (score 18):

This looks like a parsing problem, and thus I am compelled to present a solution based on parsing techniques.

While it may seem that you want to 'split' this string, I think what you actually want to do is 'tokenize' it. Tokenization or lexxing is the compilation step before parsing. I have amended my original example in an edit to implement a proper recursive decent parser here. This is the easiest way to implement a parser by hand.

```
import re

patterns = [
    ('number', re.compile('\d+')),
    ('*', re.compile(r'\*')),
    ('/', re.compile(r'\/')),
    ('+', re.compile(r'\+')),
    ('-', re.compile(r'\-')),
]
whitespace = re.compile('\W+')

def tokenize(string):
    while string:

        # strip off whitespace
        m = whitespace.match(string)
        if m:
            string = string[m.end():]

        for tokentype, pattern in patterns:
            m = pattern.match(string)
            if m:
                yield tokentype, m.group(0)
                string = string[m.end():]

def parseNumber(tokens):
    tokentype, literal = tokens.pop(0)
    assert tokentype == 'number'
    return int(literal)

def parseMultiplication(tokens):
    product = parseNumber(tokens)
    while tokens and tokens[0][0] in ('*', '/'):
        tokentype, literal = tokens.pop(0)
        if tokentype == '*':
            product *= parseNumber(tokens)
        elif tokentype == '/':
            product /= parseNumber(tokens)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Parse Error, unexpected %s %s" % (tokentype, literal))

    return product

def parseAddition(tokens):
    total = parseMultiplication(tokens)
    while tokens and tokens[0][0] in ('+', '-'):
        tokentype, literal = tokens.pop(0)
        if tokentype == '+':
            total += parseMultiplication(tokens)
        elif tokentype == '-':
            total -= parseMultiplication(tokens)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Parse Error, unexpected %s %s" % (tokentype, literal))

    return total

def parse(tokens):
    tokenlist = list(tokens)
    returnvalue = parseAddition(tokenlist)
    if tokenlist:
        print 'Unconsumed data', tokenlist
    return returnvalue

def main():
    string = '2+24*48/32'
    for tokentype, literal in tokenize(string):
        print tokentype, literal

    print parse(tokenize(string))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Implementation of handling of brackets is left as an exercise for the reader. This example will correctly do multiplication before addition.

Comment: I'm reading up on tokenizing now to understand it. So I'm not able too say where the problem is though I think it's in the fact that this script will eval * and / at the same time, which is incorrect. 8/2*2 this string should print a result of 2, but it prints a result of 8.

Comment: excuse me im wrong, always took bomdas literally turns out multiplication and division are equal in order of predecnce and whichever is occurs first is evaluated first

Comment: In `tokenize`: Why use `re` to remove whitespace over a built-in string function?

Answer (score 18):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\d+|\D+', '2+24*48/32=10')

['2', '+', '24', '*', '48', '/', '32', '=', '10']
```

Matches consecutive digits or consecutive non-digits.

Each match is returned as a new element in the list.

Depending on the usage, you may need to alter the regular expression. Such as if you need to match numbers with a decimal point.

```
>>> re.findall(r'[0-9\.]+|[^0-9\.]+', '2+24*48/32=10.1')

['2', '+', '24', '*', '48', '/', '32', '=', '10.1']
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a parsing problem, so neither regex not split() are the "good" solution. Use a parser generator instead.

I would look closely at [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/). There have also been some decent articles about pyparsing in the [Python Magazine](http://pymag.phparch.com/).

Answer (score 5):

> > > s = "2+24*48/32"
> > >
> > > p = re.compile(r'(\W+)')
> > >
> > > p.split(s)

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> splitter = re.compile(r'([+*/])')
>>> splitter.split("2+24*48/32")
```

You can expand the regular expression to include any other characters you want to split on.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution to this would be to avoid writing a calculator like that altogether. Writing an RPN parser is much simpler, and doesn't have any of the ambiguity inherent in writing math with infix notation.

```
import operator, math
calc_operands = {
    '+': (2, operator.add),
    '-': (2, operator.sub),
    '*': (2, operator.mul),
    '/': (2, operator.truediv),
    '//': (2, operator.div),
    '%': (2, operator.mod),
    '^': (2, operator.pow),
    '**': (2, math.pow),
    'abs': (1, operator.abs),
    'ceil': (1, math.ceil),
    'floor': (1, math.floor),
    'round': (2, round),
    'trunc': (1, int),
    'log': (2, math.log),
    'ln': (1, math.log),
    'pi': (0, lambda: math.pi),
    'e': (0, lambda: math.e),
}

def calculate(inp):
    stack = []
    for tok in inp.split():
        if tok in self.calc_operands:
            n_pops, func = self.calc_operands[tok]
            args = [stack.pop() for x in xrange(n_pops)]
            args.reverse()
            stack.append(func(*args))
        elif '.' in tok:
            stack.append(float(tok))
        else:
            stack.append(int(tok))
    if not stack:
        raise ValueError('no items on the stack.')
    return stack.pop()
    if stack:
        raise ValueError('%d item(s) left on the stack.' % len(stack))

calculate('24 38 * 32 / 2 +')
```

Comment: Why don't you just go implement forth, it'll only be 5 more lines!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> my_string = "2+24*48/32"
>>> my_list = re.findall(r"-?\d+|\S", my_string)
>>> print my_list

['2', '+', '24', '*', '48', '/', '32']
```

This will do the trick. I have encountered this kind of problem before.

Answer (score 0):

i'm sure Tim meant

```
splitter = re.compile(r'([\D])').
```

if you copy exactly what he has down you only get the `digits` not the `operators`.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question exactly, but I believe it solves what you're trying to achieve. I would add it as a comment, but I don't have permission to do so yet.

I personally would take advantage of Python's maths functionality directly with exec:

> expression = "2+24*48/32"
>   **exec** "result = " + expression
>   **print** result
>   38

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't it be preferable to use `result = eval(expression)`?

Comment: Indeed it would; my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good way that I always use when splitting str with different special characters. However, this code does not work with _, if there is a _ in the str you want to split, you might need to do another split one more time.

```
import re
  
  
# initializing string  
data = "2+24*48/32"
  
# printing original string  
print("The original string is : " + data) 
  
# Using re.findall() 
# Splitting characters in String 
res = re.findall(r"[\w']+", data)
  
# printing result  
print("The list after performing split functionality : " + str(res))
```