# string to list conversion in python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string.

```
s = '1989, 1990'
```

I want to convert that to list using python & i want output as,

```
s = ['1989', '1990']
```

Is there any fastest one liner way for the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split a string into a list Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88613/how-do-i-split-a-string-into-a-list-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [split method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> '1989, 1990'.split(', ')
['1989', '1990']
```

But you might want to:

1. remove spaces using [replace](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)
2. split by ','

As such:

```
>>> '1989, 1990,1991'.replace(' ', '').split(',')
['1989', '1990', '1991']
```

This will work better if your string comes from user input, as the user may forget to hit space after a comma.

Comment: "This will work better if your string comes from user input, as the user may forget to hit space after a comma." thats helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, please don't forget to [close the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you are done. This will save time from others who are reading unanswered questions to find someone with an unsolved issue to help

Answer (score 8):

Use **list comprehensions**:

```
s = '1989, 1990'
[x.strip() for x in s.split(',')]
```

Short and easy.

*Additionally, this has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4071407/589206) many times!*

Comment: This is a much better answer - replacing all spaces could affect the data, stripping the split items is a much better idea.

Answer (score 4):

Call the `split` function:

```
myList = s.split(', ')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print s.replace(' ','').split(',')
```

First removes spaces, then splits by comma.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r"\s*,\s*", "1999,2000, 1999 ,1998 , 2001")
['1999', '2000', '1999', '1998', '2001']
```

The expression `\s*,\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters, a comma and zero or more whitespace characters again.

Answer (score 1):

i created generic method for this :

```
def convertToList(v):
    '''
    @return: input is converted to a list if needed
    '''
    if type(v) is list:
        return v
    elif v == None:
        return []
    else:
        return [v]
```

Maybe it is useful for your project.

```
converToList(s)
```