# How would I convert a string into a list of tokens in Python?

Tags: python, string

When I input this:

```
>>>tokenize('<[2{12.5 6.0}](3 -4 5)>')
```

I want to get this back:

```
['<', '[', 2, '{', 12.5, 6.0, '}', ']', '(', 3, -4, 5, ')', '>']
```

Basically, how would I keep it so that the input converts everything into the list while keeping the numbers their original value.

Comment: Are you looking for a lex tool in Python? You could try PLY http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ .

Comment: Split the string into a list of individual characters.  Iterate over the list once, chunking number-like characters (digits, period, hyphen) together.  Iterate over the list again, converting the chunks to integers or floats.  You're done.

Comment: I gave a specific solution below, but more generally, think of it as two tasks: you figure out what's a lexeme first, and then make your token second. So once you have a substring that matches your rule for an int, then you convert it to one, or if it matches your rule for a float, you convert it to one of those, and so on. The rest you want to return as is, so making your token means just returning the substring.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [tokenizer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tokenize.html), it gives you almost same result as you expected except for the negative number like `-4`, but it is pretty close.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import tokenize
str = '<[2{12.5 6.0}](3 -4 5)>'
tokens = tokenize.generate_tokens(StringIO(str).readline)
result = [x[1] for x in tokens]
```

Here is the result:

```
['[', '2', '{', '12.5', '6.0', '}', ']', '(', '3', '-', '4', '5', ')', '>', '']
```

Comment: Nice but the tokens are specific to Python and not configurable.

Answer (score 0):

So, to brute-force it, you can use `list(your_string)`, but be sure to then identify what should be grouped together, appending items to the elements as you go.

Other solutions could have regular-expressions, simple grammar libraries, etc. And would be arguably easier to understand.

EDIT: for the non-integer #s, you can also note that when encountering such a number, go ahead and mutate the previous index of the new, parsed list of tokens, and when you reach the next number, closure, token, etc, you'll make a brand-new element to the list.

assuming you put everything into a new list as strings, here is *a* way of getting your floats & ints back:

```
for i, e in enumerate(tokenized):
    if e.isdigit():
        tokenized[i] = int(e)
    elif '.' in e:
        tokenized[i] = float(e)
    elif '-' in e and not '.' in e:
        tokenized[i] = int(e)
```

The end result is what you want:

```
['<', '[', 2, '{', 12.5, 6.0, '}', ']', '(', 3, -4, 5, ')', '>']
```

Comment: Also, is this input supposed to be modeled against the question's input? Can it be longer? More advanced? Does it always start with '<' and end with '>'?

Answer (score 0):

[re.split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) is probably what you want.  See a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88613/how-do-i-split-a-string-into-a-list).

After you split the string into a list, you can iterate over it and convert the numeric members to actual numbers using `int()` and `float()`.

Answer (score 0):

A [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) solution

```
tokens = (
    'LT', 'GT', 'LPAREN', 'RPAREN', 'LBRACKET', 'RBRACKET', 'LBRACE', 'RBRACE',
    'FLOAT', 'INTEGER',
)

t_LT = r'<'
t_GT = r'>'
t_LPAREN = r'\('
t_RPAREN = r'\)'
t_LBRACKET = r'\['
t_RBRACKET = r'\]'
t_LBRACE = r'{'
t_RBRACE = r'}'
t_ignore = r' '

def t_FLOAT(t):
    r'-?\d*[.]\d+'
    t.value = float(t.value)
    return t

def t_INTEGER(t):
    r'-?\d+'
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t

def t_error(t):
    raise ValueError('invalid input')

import ply.lex as lex
lex.lex()

lex.input('<[2{12.5 6.0}](3 -4 5)>')
tokens = list(iter(lex.token, None))
for t in tokens:
    print repr(t.type), repr(t.value)
print '>', [t.value for t in tokens]
```

Output:

```
'LT' '<'
'LBRACKET' '['
'INTEGER' 2
'LBRACE' '{'
'FLOAT' 12.5
'FLOAT' 6.0
'RBRACE' '}'
'RBRACKET' ']'
'LPAREN' '('
'INTEGER' 3
'INTEGER' -4
'INTEGER' 5
'RPAREN' ')'
'GT' '>'
> ['<', '[', 2, '{', 12.5, 6.0, '}', ']', '(', 3, -4, 5, ')', '>']
```

You need PLY installed. To install it, simply

```
# pip install ply
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = '<[2{12.5 6.0}](3 -4 5)>'
p = re.compile(r"([-+]?(?:(?:\d*\.\d+)|(?:\d+\.?)))|(\S)")

conv = lambda n: float(n) if '.' in n else int(n)

[conv(m.group(1)) if m.lastindex==1 else m.group(2) for m in p.finditer(s)]
```

out:

```
['<', '[', 2, '{', 12.5, 6.0, '}', ']', '(', 3, -4, 5, ')', '>']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def tokenize(txt):

    output = []

    tokenized = re.split('([\<\>\[\]\{\}\(\)\s])',txt)

    for t in tokenized:
        if len(t.strip()) > 0:
            if re.match("^\d+?\.\d+?$",t) is None:
                if re.match("^[\d\-]\d*?$",t) is None:
                    output.append(t)
                else:
                    output.append(int(t))
            else:
                output.append(float(t))

    print(output)


tokenize('<[2{12.5 6.0}](3 -4 5)>')
```

And the Output:

```
['<', '[', 2, '{', 12.5, 6.0, '}', ']', '(', 3, -4, 5, ')', '>']
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way just use regex

```
import re
def tokenize(your_string):
    pattern = re.compile(r'([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)') # float pattern
    digital = re.compile(r'([-+]?[0-9]*$)')
    lst = []
    for item in pattern.split(your_string):
        if not item.isspace(): # remove space
            if pattern.match(item):
                if digital.match(item):
                    lst.append(int(item))
                else:
                    lst.append(float(item)) # change string to float
            else:
                lst.extend(list(item)) # make unmatched string to character list
    return lst

print tokenize('<[2{12.5 6.0}](3 -4 5)>')
```

And the result is

```
['<', '[', 2, '{', 12.5, 6.0, '}', ']', '(', 3, -4, 5, ')', '>']
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite tool for this sort of thing is [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com).

```
from pyparsing import Word, ZeroOrMore, oneOf, nums

def tokenize(s):
    number = Word(nums + '.' + '-')
    number.setParseAction(lambda x : eval(x[0]))
    punctuation = '< > [ ] ( ) { }'
    lexeme = number | oneOf(punctuation) | ' '
    tokenizer = ZeroOrMore(lexeme)

    return tokenizer.parseString(s)


print tokenize('<[2{12.5 6.0}](3 -4 5)>')
```

Outputs:

```
['<', '[', 2, '{', 12.5, 6.0, '}', ']', '(', 3, -4, 5, ')', '>']
```

As with PLY, you can install with `pip install pyparsing` (and you can install pip with `easy_install pip` if you don't have it). Also in real usage you probably would not want to create the pyparsing objects with each call, so they could be global, etc.

Comment: Also, a tip: changing oneOf(punctuation) to Suppress(oneOf(punctuation)) gives the output [2, 12.5, 6.0, 3, -4, 5]

Answer (score -2):

So this is one with a very nice solution in python

`list(my_string)` does a beginning tokenization but does not preserve the properties you like :(.

So for that we can if we want to use some slightly heavier than necessary machinery

```
import re
a = '<[2{12.5 6.0}](3 -4 5)>'
tokenized = [x in re.split(r'[[!"#$%&\'()*+,\-/:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~ ]]*',a)) if x!='']
#or also
tokens = [x in re.split(r'[[!"#$%&\'()*+,\-/:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~ ]]*',a)) if x]
```

this can be used in any language/whiteboard expression and the puncuation is just from strings.punctuation, you can customize to delimit on *anything* that can be expressed with a regex - which is almost everything.

use re.compile to precompile the expression if you are running this on a giant string - you get better optimizations. also under certain constraints you can use automata for some of this ;) and that gives MASSIVE benefits

Comment: He wants to keep the numbers their original value. if you do list(), then you tokenize the numbers to digits as well. Please try.

Comment: It does add them to a list. However, it breaks apart the whole numbers. I want the 12.5 to remain as [12.5, 6.0]. Not ['1', '2', '.', '5']